# Trying to getComputedStyle from parent element/Component in React

Tags: css, reactjs, dom, components, getcomputedstyle

I need to get computed background color a parent element to pass to an Image component. This is needed as I'm using the Contentful API to render images on the fly, and I have to supply a bg color query param.

Currently this isn't working:

```js
import Card, { CardContent } from 'components/Card';
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

import Image from 'components/Image';
import Link from 'react-router/lib/Link';

export default class Expertise extends Component {
  
  componentDidMount()   {
    console.log(window.getComputedStyle(this._bg, null).getPropertyValue('backgroundColor'));
  }
  
  _renderColumned() {
    return (
      <Card
        layout={this.props.layout}
        additionalClasses={['expertise-item-container']}
        automationId={`expertise-container-${this.props.id}`}
        ref={node => (this._bg = node)}
      >
        <CardContent layout={'text'} theme={'transparent'} padded>
          <h3 className="expertise-headline h4" data-automation={`expertise-headline-${this.props.id}`}>
            <span className="h1 card-grid-enumeration">{this.props.displayNumber}</span>
            {this.props.headline}
          </h3>
          <p className="expertise-description" data-automation={`expertise-description-${this.props.id}`}>{this.props.description}</p>
          { this.props.url && this.props.linkText ?
            <Link className="expertise-link" data-automation={`expertise-link-${this.props.id}`} to={this.props.url}>{this.props.linkText}</Link> :
              null }
        </CardContent>
        <CardContent layout={'image'} theme={'transparent'} padded>
          <Image url={this.props.media.url} alt={this.props.media.alt} aspectRatio={'rectangle'} fit={'pad'} automationId={`expertise-image-${this.props.id}`} background={"F4F4F4"} />
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    );
  }

  _renderStacked() {
    return (
      <div
        className="expertise-item-container centered"
        data-automation={`expertise-container-${this.props.id}`}
        // ref={image => (this._image = image)}
        ref={node => (this._bg = node)}
      >
        <h3 className="expertise-headline h4" data-automation={`expertise-headline-${this.props.id}`}>
          <span className="h1 card-grid-enumeration">{this.props.displayNumber}</span>&nbsp;
          {this.props.headline}
        </h3>
        <p className="expertise-description" data-automation={`expertise-description-${this.props.id}`}>{this.props.description}</p>
        <Image url={this.props.media.url} alt={this.props.media.alt} aspectRatio={'banner'} fit={'pad'} automationId={`expertise-image-${this.props.id}`} ref={node => (this._image = node)} background={"F4F4F4"} />
        { this.props.url && this.props.linkText ?
          <Link className="expertise-link" data-automation={`expertise-link-${this.props.id}`} to={this.props.url}>{this.props.linkText}</Link> :
            null }
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.layout === 'columned' ?
      this._renderColumned() :
      this._renderStacked();
  }

}

Expertise.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  layout: PropTypes.oneOf(['columned', 'stacked']).isRequired,
  headline: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  description: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  media: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  url: PropTypes.string,
  linkText: PropTypes.string,
  displayNumber: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Specifically, `getComputedStyle` reports `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

Just trying to get the `background-color` successfully, eventually I would compare this to the default given in the background prop to the Image component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you can't get computed styles before component has been rendered (the same reason you can't get `ref`). You can store a parent `bgcolor` style in its local `state` (it will be `null` or `undefined` ot `white` at the beginning, whatever) and pass it to component's children. After the component has been rendered (`componentDidMount()` or `window.addEventListener("load", ...)`) you can call parent `setState()` method to set its `bgcolor` state (). Then this component will be rerendered and its children will access its `bgcolor`.

Comment: I want to point out that according to: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats, the ref gets called twice, one where the element is null since it clears out the element.